# Alter existing jQuery to make span placeholder

Tags: jquery, placeholder

I have some jQuery that provides a placeholder as long as my `<label for="">` matches the `input` name and ID. However, that's not the case so I've decided to just use a `<span>` for the placeholder instead. Can someone help alter my jQuery to make the `<span>` class "holder" I'm using work? The goal is to have the placeholder stay on focus, disappear when input exists, then reappear if the input disappears.

**Here's the HTML I'm using:**

```
<div id="placeholder">
  <span class="holder">This is the placeholder...</span>
  <%= f.text_area :body, :id =>"Placeholder" %>
</div>
```

**And my current jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('textarea').keyup(function() {
        if ($(this).val().length) {
            $('label[for="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').hide();
        } else {
            $('label[for="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$(function() {
    $("span.holder + textarea").keyup(function() {
        if($(this).val().length) {
            $(this).prev('span.holder').hide();
        } else {
            $(this).prev('span.holder').show();
        }
    });        
});
```

This should work for all textareas on page if they have `span.holder` preceding them.

Answer (score 1):

You want to bind to the [`focus`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) and [`blur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) events and absolutely position the `<span>` over the `<textarea>`. Start with some CSS:

```
#placeholder {
    position: relative;
}

.holder {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    display: none;
}
```

And then the jQuery:

```
$('.holder').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('textarea').focus();
});
$('#Placeholder').focus(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.holder').hide();
});
$('#Placeholder').blur(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.val().length == 0)
        $(this).siblings('.holder').show();
});
$('#Placeholder').blur();
```

The final `$('#Placeholder').blur()` call is there to initialize the state of the `<span>` so that it will be in the right state if the `<textarea>` starts out with content.

And a quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/PLrf3/1/

BTW, having `id="placeholder"` and `id="Placeholder"` in the same page might lead to some confusion. You would be better off choosing a standard scheme (`camelCase`, `words-and-hyphens`, or whatever) for your `id` attributes and sticking to it. Just a case difference might be confusing and might look like a typo.